# How to pass values throuh link in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to pass values through

```
<a href= <?php  $this->baseUrl()/admin/registration/activate/>  </a>
```

this is my code an i have to pass user Id to this url to activate user. what I have to use I wll get my user id `<?php $this->userid; ?>` 
please help
my action  is

```
public function activateAction()
    {  // Administrator actvate user
        $user_name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('user_name');
        $reg = new clmsRegistrationModel();
        $reg->setActive($user_name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your action

```
$this->_request->getParam('prop_id', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have Controller Index and Action Customer, so you can build you link with an Zend Framework View helper (inside your view script):

```
 echo $this->url(array(
      'controller' => 'index', 
      'action'     => 'customer', 
      'prop_id'    => 5
 ));
```

in your Controller:

```
customerAction() {
      $propId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('prop_id');
}
```

After your comment (add to your view script):

```
<?php $postUrl = $this->url(array(
     'controller' => 'admin',
     'action'     => 'registration',
     'activate'   => $this->userid     
)); ?>

<a href="<?php echo $postUrl; ?>"> Activate </a>
```

Comment: okey Thanks, the code provided will work  in my particular case prop_id is not static  I will change according to the user. So how can I pass a parameter through  URL in generic case

Comment: <a href= <?php  $this->baseUrl()/admin/registration/activate/?>  this is my code an i have to pass user Id to this url to activate user. what I have to use I wll get my user id <?php $this->userid; ?> please help

Comment: Some errors are getting now  instead of getting value it act as an action  http://localhost/CLMS/admin/registration/activate/abc1  here abc is my user id it is passing  not as a value  registration is my controller and  admin is my module  please help

Comment: the syntax is: MODULE/CONTROLLER/ACTION/PARAM/VALUE

Comment: <?php $postUrl = $this->url(array(
        'controller' => 'registration',
     'action'     => 'activate',
     ''   => $user['user_name']     
  )); ?>  what change  I have to make in this ?